# Application(mfc) failing in Release build due to compiler optimization but working fine in debug build

Tags: c++, mfc

I am facing issue with Release build. Application works fine in Debug build but in release build a pointer initialized to hold object of another class is getting different address allocation and thus causing corruption to its values.

```
My main application class is K32App
code in K32App.h file 
CSheetPrintManager* m_pSheetPrintManager;
CSheetPrintManager* GetSheetPrintManager() { return m_pSheetPrintManager; }

In file K32App.cpp
K32App::K32App()
{
  m_pSheetPrintManager= NULL;
} 
BOOL K32App::InitInstance()
{
  if(!m_pSheetPrintManager)
    m_pSheetPrintManager= new CSheetPrintManager();
}
K32App::~K32App()
{
  if(m_pSheetPrintManager)
    delete(m_pSheetPrintManager)
}


 In my file  CSheetPrintManager.cpp
 void CSheetPrintManager::CSheetPrintManager()
 {
   //Initialized all member variables to default values.
   Init();

 }
 void CSheetPrintManager::Init()
 {
   m_nSheetType = SheetIllegalNone;  //long
   m_sBankEntry.Empty();         //CString
   m_bHistorical = FALSE;        //BOOL
   m_bDebitDetailsSet = FALSE;  //BOOL
   m_mapRequested.RemoveAll(); // Type CMap<long,long,CString,CString&> 
 }
```

During application startup, when it reaches

```
  if(!m_pSheetPrintManager)
    CSheetPrintManager= new CSheetPrintManager();
```

and tries to create object of m_pSheetPrintManager, **'this'** pointer inside CSheetPrintManager.cpp shows valid address (0x03768ce0) at breakpoint just at curly brace {, once I step further into CSheetPrintManager.Init(), **'this'** gets different location and starts point to another address(0x0000000) and then further moving it starts pointing another location(0x03786ce0) and then on reaching      `m_mapRequested.RemoveAll();` 
**'this'** is pointing some other location.
returning back to main app file C32App.cpp , I get following for 'm_pSheetPrintManager' CXX0030 Error 'expression cannot be evaluated" in Auto window.
and appplication continues to run. See what get when hover mouse of m_pSheetPrintManager  (can't post image because need 10 reputations for it :) so linking it)
[studio Auto window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXmuO.png)

In debug mode, I get m_pSheetPrintManager pointing to same location during all application processing and members always remain properly initialized.

But in Release mode, m_pSheetPrintManager continues to point (address value shown in Auto window) different location. and all member variables of class CSheetPrintManager showing different garbage(Uninitialized) values with each line of processing inside CSheetPrintManager Class.

**If I disable C++ compiler optimization in Release-Mode then it works fine without any issue.**

Any help/guidance/suggestion is most appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

PS: This is my first question here so please excuse in case missing something to point or express properly.

Comment: What you see in the *Autos* window is mostly useless, when inspecting optimized code. You have two options: Single-step through assembly code, or switch to Visual Studio 2013 or later and enable the [/Zo (Enhance Optimized Debugging)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dn785163.aspx) compiler option.

Comment: @IInspectable this is legacy code and currently I am using studio 2005. I will try to port this to 2013 but can't say it will compile with all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info: Is `CSheetPrintManager` capsuled in a dll? How does the declaration look? This way I only can play guessing games... :-/

Consider to derive from `CObject` and use [DECLARE DYNCREATE and IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56302tyt.aspx) for your `CSheetPrintManager`class. You can then `VERIFY()`in your Release version if it's a valid object using `CObject::`[IsKindOf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b7tsah76.aspx).

Try [#pragma pack()](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/14659/) to define how padding is done in your class, especially if you optimized for size in the Release version and having mixed-up Debug and Release dlls.